# Format a string as shown below

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of books and published dates that I would have to format as shown below

```
Book    Date    Book    Date
ABC.....12-18   1ABC....12-18     
ABCD....12-18   ABC123..12-18        
ABCDEF..12-18   ABz.....12-18       
X.......12-18   ABCzz...12-18       
AIJKL...12-18   ABCdfs..12-18 
ABC.....12-18   1ABC....12-18     
ABCD....12-18   ABC123..12-18        
ABCDEF..12-18   ABz.....12-18       
X.......12-18   ABCzz...12-18       
AIJKL...12-18   ABCdfs..12-18
```

I tried stringbuilder

```
List<Book> lstBooks = GetBooks();    
StringBuilder books = new StringBuilder();
books = books.AppendLine(" Book    Date    Book    Date ");

foreach (Book b in lstBooks )
{
    books.Append(b.Name + ".....".PadLeft(5 - b.CompletedDate.Length) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

But showing the data side by side is where I am stuck, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to take 2 at a time, since there are 2 books on each line

Comment: Just a note: `StringBuilder` has an `AppendLine` method so you don't need to concatenate the `NewLine` on there...

Comment: So you're not sorting the items by anything, you just want to format it into two columns?

Comment: please be explicit about what you're trying to accomplish.  That is, I think you're trying to get two records at a time.. is that correct? if so, update your question stating that

Comment: you should considering using for loop and indexes, or potentially a Zip operation might work.. in a creative means

Comment: Do you care about the order?

Comment: no I dont care about the order in which they show up

Comment: yes I am not sorting by anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Displaying data in uniformly-sized columns requires two loops through the data, the first loop is to get the maximum length of text to display, then the second loop then uses `PadRight` to add enough '`.`' characters to left-align the text as you have in your example.
- Use `PadRight` to left-align text, and `PadLeft` to right-align text.
- `PadLeft` and `PadRight`'s argument is the *maximum* string length and is not the number of padding characters to add.
- Use an explicit date format `MM-yy` to ensure all output is 5 characters (and to avoid ambiguity you should use ISO 8601 formats and always avoid 2-digit years).
- Displaying multiple columns on the same line requires a separate counter to count the number of items written to the current line so far and only adding a line-break after writing 2 items to a line.

```
    List<Book> books = GetBooks();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    const Int32 maxPerLine = 2;

    Int32 longestName = books.Max( b => b.Name.Length ) + 1; // Determine the width of the column by finding the longest text in the data. `Max` is a Linq extension method. Then add 1 to ensure there's always at least 1 dot between the name and the date.

    // Render column headings:
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < maxPerLine; i++ )
    {
        sb.Append( "Book".PadRight( longestName ) );
        sb.Append( "Date".PadRight( 5 ) );
        sb.Append( "  " );
    }
    sb.AppendLine();

    // Render the book names and dates:
    Int32 i = 0;
    foreach( Book book in books ) 
    {
        if( i > 0 && i % maxPerLine == 0 ) sb.AppendLine();

        String namePadded = book.Name.PadRight( longestName + 1, '.' ); // +1 
        sb.Append( namePadded );
        sb.Append( book.CompletedDate.ToString("MM-yy") );

        sb.Append( "  " );

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: yea.. determining the longestName for padding is a good approach, but I think you still need to subtract `book.Name.Length` from it in your operation there.

Comment: also, you may want to add 1 to that longestName, otherwise the longest name will have no separator to the date.

Comment: @BrettCaswell I ran this in Linqpad and got expected results. You don't need to subtract any length because `PadRight` does that for you.

Comment: ah.. you're right.. I was being presumptuous.. sorry. I should have double checked that before I posted the comment - not sure what "not aligned" is suggesting here then..

Answer (score 3):

So I'll give you an option that you'll need to expand on to work for *all* scenarios but it should get you going if you like it. I'm also using a list of strings as a simple example; you should have no problem applying it to `Book`s.

You have a single list of items that you need to be displayed in two even columns so what you can do is split the original in two and `Zip` them back up; like so:

```
var strings = new List<string>
{
    "first",
    "second",
    "third",
    "fourth"
};

var half = strings.Count / 2;
strings
    .Take(half)
    .Zip(strings.Skip(half), (f, s) => $"{f} : {s}")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output:
first : third 
second : fourth

Follow up: *What happens when there's an odd number of elements?*

Comment: regarding your follow up.. the zip follows same consideration as the for-loop approach I've provided.. you'll need to determine on and conditionally handle the last record..

Answer (score 2):

One way to output a list of items in column format is to determine the number of rows (by dividing the item count by the column count, and adding 1 if the count is not evenly divisible by the number of columns), and then output "column count" number of items formatted to the column width.

We can write a method that takes in a list of strings, and then outputs the strings into columns of a specific width:

```
public static void OutputInColumns(List<string> items, int columnCount,
    int columnWidth, string header = null)
{
    // If no columns or no items are specified, return
    if (columnCount == 0 || items?.Any() != true) return;
    var count = items.Count;

    // Determine how many rows we need and fill in last row with empty values if needed
    var rows = count / columnCount + (count % columnCount > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 
        columnCount - count % columnCount).Select(x => string.Empty));

    // Output our column headers
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ║ ",
            Enumerable.Range(0, columnCount)
                .Select(x => header.PadRight(columnWidth, ' '))));

    // Output a divider
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("═╬═",
            Enumerable.Range(0, columnCount)
                .Select(x => new string('═', columnWidth))));

    // Output our row data
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        // For each row, add a line with items separated by a tab
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ║ ", items
            .Skip(row * columnCount)
            .Take(columnCount)
            .Select(item => item
                .Substring(0, Math.Min(item.Length, columnWidth))
                .PadRight(columnWidth, ' '))));
    }
}
```

Next we can write a method that takes in a `Book` and outputs a string in the format `"Title....PublishDate"`. We can let the user pass in a value for the width of the `Title` portion, and default to showing the whole title if a width isn't specified:

```
public static string AsColumnString(Book book, int columnWidth = 0)
{
    if (columnWidth < 1) columnWidth = book.Title.Length + 8;
    var name = book.Title.Substring(0, Math.Min(book.Title.Length, columnWidth - 8))
        .PadRight(columnWidth - 5, '.');
    var date = book.PublishDate.ToString("MM-yy");
    return $"{name}{date}";
}
```

Now, if we have a list of books, we can easily print them in any number of columns (with any column width we choose):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var books = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book {Title = "Ulysses", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("February 2, 1922")},
        new Book {Title = "Don Quixote", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("January 16, 1605")},
        new Book {Title = "The Great Gatsby", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("April 10, 1925")},
        new Book {Title = "Moby Dick", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("October 18, 1851")},
        new Book {Title = "War and Peace", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("January 1, 1869")},
        new Book {Title = "Hamlet", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("January 1, 1603")},
        new Book {Title = "To Kill a Mockingbird", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("July 11, 1960")},
        new Book {Title = "The Catcher in the Rye", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("July 16, 1951")},
        new Book {Title = "The Hobbit", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("September 21, 1937")},
        new Book {Title = "Fahrenheit 451", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("October 19, 1953")},
        new Book {Title = "The Handmaid's Tale", PublishDate = DateTime.Parse("January 1, 1985")},
    };

    // Select the longest book title and add '8' for the three dots and the date
    var columnWidth = books.Select(b => b.Title.Length).Max() + 8;
    var columnCount = 2;

    // Create our header for each column
    var header = "Book".PadRight(columnWidth - 5) + "Date";

    OutputInColumns(books.Select(b => AsColumnString(b, columnWidth)).ToList(), 
        columnCount, columnWidth, header);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Here's another example, only this time using 4 narrower columns:

```
// Note we can make our columns smaller and add more of them
columnWidth = 16;
columnCount = 4;
header = "Book".PadRight(columnWidth - 5) + "Date";
OutputInColumns(books.Select(b => AsColumnString(b, columnWidth)).ToList(), columnCount, 
    columnWidth, header);
```

**Output**

[image]

Side note: You may want to show the full year as a date, since the samples I used span over multiple centuries, the last two digits aren't very useful. :)

### Heading

Comment: After executing your solution I am getting an exception $exception {"Index and length must refer to a location within the string.\r\nParameter name: length"} System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException at var name = book.Title.Substring(0, columnWidth - 8).PadRight(columnWidth - 5, '.');

Comment: Oh, good catch! I had updated code on my machine but forgot to publish it here. I've updated the sample now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Book> lstBooks = GetBooks();
        StringBuilder books = new StringBuilder();
        books = books.AppendLine("Book    Date    Book    Date");

        string dots = "........";

        foreach (Book b in lstBooks)
        {
            string neededDots = dots;

            for (int i = 1; i <= b.Name.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && neededDots.Length > 1)
                {
                    neededDots = neededDots.Remove(0, 1);
                }
            }

            books.AppendLine(b.Name + neededDots.PadLeft(5 - b.CompletedDate.Length) + b.CompletedDate
                + "   "
                + b.Name + neededDots.PadLeft(5 - b.CompletedDate.Length) + b.CompletedDate);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(books);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Output:

```
Book    Date    Book    Date
ABC.....12-18   ABC.....12-18
ABCD....12-18   ABCD....12-18
ABCDEF..12-18   ABCDEF..12-18
X.......12-18   X.......12-18
AIJKL...12-18   AIJKL...12-18
ABC.....12-18   ABC.....12-18
ABCD....12-18   ABCD....12-18
ABCDEF..12-18   ABCDEF..12-18
X.......12-18   X.......12-18
AIJKL...12-18   AIJKL...12-18
```

Answer (score 0):

In consideration to the other answers - I'll provide the For-Loop using index approach.

---

Define your types with Mock data

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletedDate { get; set; }
}

List<Book> lstBooks = new List<Book>
{
    new Book { Name = "ABC", CompletedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Book { Name = "1ABC", CompletedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Book { Name = "XYZ", CompletedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Book { Name = "2XYZ", CompletedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Book { Name = "123ABC", CompletedDate = DateTime.Now },
};
```

***Sample Code***

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
string completedDateFormat = "MM-dd";

var spacePadding = 4;
var bookDatePadding = Math.Max(5, lstBooks.Max(b => b.Name.Length)) + 1;
var dateSpacePadding = completedDateFormat.Length;

string title = string.Join(string.Empty.PadRight(spacePadding, ' '),
    string.Join(string.Empty, "Book".PadRight(bookDatePadding, ' '), "Date".PadRight(dateSpacePadding, ' ')),
    string.Join(string.Empty, "Book".PadRight(bookDatePadding, ' '), "Date".PadRight(dateSpacePadding, ' ')));

sBuilder.AppendLine(title);

for (int i = 1, max = lstBooks.Count; i < max; i += 2)
{
    sBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(string.Empty.PadRight(spacePadding, ' '),
        string.Join(string.Empty, lstBooks[i - 1].Name.PadRight(bookDatePadding, '.'), lstBooks[i - 1].CompletedDate.ToString(completedDateFormat)),
        string.Join(string.Empty, lstBooks[i].Name.PadRight(bookDatePadding, '.'), lstBooks[i - 1].CompletedDate.ToString(completedDateFormat))));
}

// Determine if Last record is accounted for by loop logic by looking at the remainder of a modular operation
var appendLastRecord = lstBooks.Count % 2 != 0;
if (appendLastRecord)
    sBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(string.Empty, lstBooks.Last().Name.PadRight(bookDatePadding, '.'), lstBooks.Last().CompletedDate.ToString(completedDateFormat)));

Console.Write(sBuilder.ToString());
```

This will output the following

```
Book   Date     Book   Date 
ABC....10-24    1ABC...10-24
XYZ....10-24    2XYZ...10-24
123ABC.10-24
```

The For-Loop defines `i` as an iterator on the index;

- this initial value will be `1` and we'll add `2` for each iteration of the lopp until `i` is greater then `max`, or rather - the length of the list. (`i - 1` will then represent the earlier record, `i` will be later one (or even record, but in a 0-index array mind you)

Because of this approach, we have a scenario where the last record may not be represented in the loop - which is fine since the body of this loop is designed to always handles 2 records at a time, and we'll need to handle a single record in that event.

#### EDIT 1:

Including padding logic (though the desire of this answer is to present the for-loop index approach, not necessarily provide a completed\working sample)